# Compare array elements and determine which element's string is the part of another in bash

Tags: string, bash, compare, contains

I have an array:

```
src_dir=( /etc /var/www /var /var/html /home/user)
```

I want output like this:

```
/etc
/var contains /var/www /var/html
/home/user
```

I've tried so far:

```
src_dir=( /etc /var/www /var /var/html /home/user)
declare exclude
for src in ${src_dir[@]}; do
    if ! [[ " $src " =~ $exclude ]]; then
        exclude+=("$src")
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

src_dir=( /etc /var/www /var /var/html /home/user)

for src in "${src_dir[@]}"; do
    # Determine if $src contains other elements ($is_container), and which
    # elements contain it ($containers)
    is_container=0
    containers=()   # Elements that this element is part of
    for src2 in "${src_dir[@]}"; do
        if [[ $src2 == "$src" ]] ; then
            # Don't count an element as being part of itself
            continue
        elif [[ $src == *"$src2"* ]]; then
            is_container=1
            break
        elif [[ $src2 == *"$src"* ]] ; then
            containers+=( "$src2" )
        fi
    done

    # Skip elements that contain other elements.
    # Print elements elements that don't contain other elements, and any
    # elements that contain them.
    if (( is_container )) ; then
        continue
    elif (( ${#containers[*]} > 0 )) ; then
        printf '%s is contained in' "$src"
        printf ' %q' "${containers[@]}"
        printf '\n'
    else
        printf '%s\n' "$src"
    fi
done
```

- Regular expression matching (`=~`) has some oddities in Bash, and is best avoided.  Simple pattern matching with `[[ ... == ... ]]` is sufficient here.
- Elements aren't listed as being contained in other elements if they contain any elements.  So if you've got `(/home /home/user /home/user/dir)` then `/home/user` will not be listed as being contained in `/home/user/dir`.  That may not be what you want.
- Elements are compared as pure strings.  No attempt is made to check for filesystem path containment.  So, for instance, `/home/user` is considered to be contained  in `/home/user2`.  That may not be what you want.
- If an element contains two other elements, it will be listed as containing both of them.  So both `/home` and `/user` will be listed as being contained in `/home/user`.  That may not be what you want.